# Continuing / resuming with typhoeus?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, vcr, typhoeus

I have written a script using the [typhoeus](http://typhoeus.github.io) and [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) gems to pull a large amount of data into a database.  Unfortunately I have found some issues with timeouts and errors that are preventing the entire process to complete.  It turns out that `vcr` is recording these timeouts and thus has created a problem for resuming download processes.

How would / could one enable continuing / resuming of downloads with `typhoeus`?  I am looking through the documentation and various examples and have not found a solid way to programmatically control resumption of downloads with `typhoeus` (was hoping `vcr` would handle that replay, but obviously hitting the wall since it is recording failures and not seeing a way to stop that).